# Is it possible to inherit from built-in objects?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I've tried different patterns for implementing inheritance in Javascript, but none of them seem to work with built-in objects such as `Set`. For instance, using the [method described in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain):

```
function Test() {
    Set.apply(this, arguments);
}
Test.prototype = Object.create(Set.prototype, {});
Test.prototype.constructor = Test;

var test = new Test(["a", "b"]);
```

yields the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Constructor Set requires 'new'
    at Test.Set (native)
    at new Test (<anonymous>:2:9)
    at <anonymous>:1:9
```

This makes sense, since my derived object does not contain the native `Set` implementation. Is there a pattern that would support these operations, other than making a complete wrapper?

Comment: There is always [*the language specification*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-set-constructor): "*Set is not intended to be called as a function and will throw an exception when called in that manner.*" Following that are instructions for how to subclass it.

Comment: Oh, the error you're getting is saying you're calling *Set* incorrectly. If it wasn't supported you'd get a reference error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *extends* and have a call to *super*, something like:

```js
class mySet extends Set {
  constructor (iterable, name) {
    super(iterable);
    this.name = name;
  }

  // Read a Set property
  howMany () {
    return this.size;
  }

  // Call a Set method
  showEm () {
    this.forEach(v=>console.log(v));
  } 

  // Add your own methods
  // ...
}

var aSet = new mySet([0,1,2,3], 'aSet');

console.log(aSet.name);      // aSet
console.log(aSet.howMany()); // 4
aSet.showEm();               // 0 1 2 3

// Call set method directly
console.log(aSet.has(3));     // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess is asking for Set constructor.
Try this,

```
function Set(){
    // init stuff
}

function Test() {
    return new Set.apply(this, arguments);
}
Test.prototype = Object.create(Set.prototype, {});
Test.prototype.constructor = Test;

var test = new Test(["a", "b"]);
```

Comment: Did you try that?

Comment: Not actually, I wrote at first line 'I guess'

Comment: I was facing same issue once, resolved by using constructor, if you have any best option please share, will be appreciated

Comment: Well, answers are supposed to be answers, not guesses.